# Question about Approximate spectrum of a bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

We define the approximate spectrum of a bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space as 
Let H be the Hilbert space over the field $K$
$\sigma_a(T)$={$\lambda \in K$ / $\exists$ $(x_n) \in H$ and $||x||=1$ and $(T-\lambda I)x_n \rightarrow 0$}
Can anyone give an example for this spectrum?

Comment: $T(a_n)=(\frac 1 n a_n)$ on $\ell^{2}$. For this operator $0$ is in the approximate spectrum since $Te_n \to 0$.

Comment: If $A$ is self-adjoint then $\sigma(A)= \sigma_a(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $ \sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of $T$, then

$$ \partial \sigma(T) \subseteq \sigma_a(T).$$